# Pure CSS fade-in fade-out each from left to right

Tags: css

Is it possible to create a fade-in fade-out effect in pure css, each running from left to right (cf. gif)?

[image: Fade In Fade Out of desired effekt]

I implemented the fade-in hover effect with the following code:

```
input[type='submit'] {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, var(--btn-prim-bg-color) 50%, var(--color-primary) 50%) right;
    background-size: 200%;
    transition: .5s;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: none;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background-position: left;
    color: var(--color-text);
}
```

But I have problems with the fade-out on mouse leave, it runs from right to left afterwards. but it should run from left to right again (cf. gif)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction

Comment: @DanielA.White will this really allow producing that effect? The animation is not back and forth, but the out animation is in the same direction as the in animation?

Comment: actually I think this might be the use for keyframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can take advantage of the fact that some properties can be transitioned and others can happen instantly.

In this snippet the background-color of the input is changed instantly on hover, its background image which consists of a blue part and a yellow part initially is changed to a transparent part and a yellow part on hover.

The only property that is transitioned is the background sizes of the two linear gradients.

```css
input {
  background-color: yellow;
  background-image: linear-gradient(cornflowerblue, cornflowerblue), linear-gradient(yellow, yellow);
  background-size: 100% 100%, 0% 100%;
  background-position: left top, left top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: background-size 5s linear;
  border: none;
}

input:hover {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), linear-gradient(yellow, yellow);
  background-size: 0% 100%, 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<input>
```